# CSS skewX property is causing issues with foundation drop down menus

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation, skew

I'm trying to tskew the top level of menu items [successfully] - I managed to ge the li and a tags lined up correctly, but the ul.dropdown is popping up under the rest of the document elements and it's way offset to the right - with different offsets for each drop down. It alo appears to have had some transparency applied.

fiddle is here : https://jsfiddle.net/acto8k5y/5/

- you have to open the fiddle wide enough to see the non-responsive menu
- all the custom menu CSS is at the very bottom of the css panel

This is what I am using for just the skewing portion:

```
  .top-bar-section ul > li {
    margin: 0 10px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(30deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(30deg);
    -o-transform: skew(30deg);
  }


  .top-bar-section ul li > a  {
    -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-30deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-30deg);
  }

  .top-bar-section > ul > li .dropdown {
    -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-30deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-30deg);
  }
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

If you selectively disable the inverse skew on the submenu `ul`, you'll notice that the `ul` is aligned with the coloured bar below each menu item. It would seem that the skew on the `ul` element has the transform origin at the bottom of the element, with the effect that it's pushed rightwards to the visible position.

If the only element you want to skew is the coloured bar below each menu item, you might be better off replacing the skew `transform`'s with pseudo-elements to create the bevel:

```
.top-bar-section .has-dropdown::before {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
}
.top-bar-section .has-dropdown::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
}
.top-bar-section .health {
    color: #00adeb;
}
.top-bar-section .family {
    color: #3ab652;
}
.top-bar-section .community {
    color: #f59334;
}
.top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a {
    color: #000;
}
```

While the CSS is slightly more complex and verbose, it will mean there is less transforms being superimposed and will also reduce the graphical load on client browsers. Using this CSS, the dropdown menu is positioned relative to the original menu item.

See the https://jsfiddle.net/acto8k5y/6/.